# Format HTML so that new tags end up on new lines

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

My html looks like this:

```
<div class="flex items-center space-x-2"><img
        src="img/speech-bubble.svg"
        alt="Speech Bubble Icon"
    > <a
        href="#"
        class="link-blue"
    >Testing</a><span class="text-grey">(8 Dec 2020)</span></div>
```

I want my code to look like:

```
<div class="flex items-center space-x-2">
    <img
        src="img/speech-bubble.svg"
        alt="Speech Bubble Icon"
    > 
    <a
        href="#"
        class="link-blue"
    >
        Testing
    </a>
    <span class="text-grey">(8 Dec 2020)</span>
</div>
```

How do I do that in Vscode? I don't see an option to have the html tags on a new line.